# How to use customer style to show font and background colors

Tags: pandas, styles

I have a dataframe has two sets of identical columns:
I want to designe two customer's styles:

1. show whole row with background if there is any nan value
2. show font in red if two values are different from the same two columns.

Below is an screenshot of an expected result:

[image]

```
def color_null_column_yellow(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'
    c2 = 'background-color: ""'

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(c2, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    df1 = df1.where((x == np.nan).any(axis=1), c1)
    return df1

styled = data.style.apply(styler.color_null_column_yellow, axis=None)
styled.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False, merge_cells=False)
```

ValueError: style is not supported for non-unique indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=False` for default index, another problem is duplicated columns names, so necessary deduplicated columns names:

```
f = lambda x:  pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(x.nunique(axis=1).values[:, None],
                            len(x.columns), axis=1), 
                            index=x.index, columns=x.columns)

def color_null_column_yellow(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'
    c2 = 'background-color: ""'
    c3 = 'color: red'

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(c2, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)

    m2 = x.groupby(x.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis=1).apply(f) != 1
    df1 = df1.mask(x.isna().any(axis=1), c1).mask(m2, c3)
    return df1

s = data.columns.to_series()
data.columns = data.columns + '_' + s.groupby(s).cumcount().astype(str)

print (data)
   ID_0   Name_0  Age_0  ID_1   Name_1  Age_1
0   1.0    James   34.0   1.0    James   34.0
1   2.0     Kobe   39.0   2.0     Kobe   39.0
2   3.0  Michael   50.0   3.0  Michael   48.0
3   4.0     Wall   23.0   NaN      NaN    NaN
4   NaN      NaN    NaN   5.0     Nash   45.0
```

---

```
styled = data.reset_index(drop=True).style.apply(color_null_column_yellow, axis=None)
styled.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, engine='openpyxl', index=False, merge_cells=False)
```

Comment: @JasonLi - What is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: I fixed the error, the background color works now. As I comment above, the column issue

Comment: @JasonLi - What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: The columns:   ID_0   Name_0  Age_0  ID_1   Name_1  Age_1. The background color works now but I don't see the color font  for different values like the age. The issue is that the column name do not know in advance and has to be identified in runtime and can be multiple-columns. I want to keep the column name as is or has to add them back

Comment: Super! it solve the problem although the column name issue remains. But I think it is good enough!